# vba writing cells to a text document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

i have written a macro to write cell information paragraphs and tables within a word document, the problem im having is that when i run the macro the first thing to appear in the word document is a table, text under it and then another table and text under that and so on, the issue being the text underneath each table needs to go above it. im not sure what im doing wrong but here's my code so far

```
Set objword = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objdoc = objword.Documents.Add
Set objselection = objword.Selection
Set objrange = objdoc.Content

objword.Visible = True

Set objrange = objdoc.Content
objrange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseend

' write paragraph
If Cells(i, 9) <> "" Then
    objselection.TypeText Text:=Mid(CStr(Cells(i, 1)), 1, 2) & "." & Mid(CStr(Cells(i, 1)), 3, 2) & "." & Mid(CStr(Cells(i, 1)), 5, 2) & "." & Mid(CStr(Cells(i, 1)), 7, 2) & " " & CStr(Cells(i, 9))
    objselection.TypeParagraph
Else
    If Cells(i, 8) <> "" Then
        objselection.TypeText Text:=Mid(CStr(Cells(i, 1)), 1, 2) & "." & Mid(CStr(Cells(i, 1)), 3, 2) & "." & Mid(CStr(Cells(i, 1)), 5, 2) & " " & CStr(Cells(i, 8))
        objselection.TypeParagraph
    Else
        If Cells(i, 7) <> "" Then
            objselection.TypeText Text:=Mid(CStr(Cells(i, 1)), 1, 2) & "." & Mid(CStr(Cells(i, 1)), 3, 2) & " " & CStr(Cells(i, 7))
            objselection.TypeParagraph
        Else
            If Cells(i, 6) <> "" Then
                objselection.TypeText Text:=Mid(CStr(Cells(i, 1)), 1, 2) & " " & CStr(Cells(i, 6))
                objselection.TypeParagraph
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

With objselection
    .TypeText Text:=Cells(i, 6) & "|" & Cells(i, 7) & "|" & Cells(i, 8) & "|" & Cells(i, 9)
    .TypeParagraph
    .TypeText Text:=CStr(Worksheets("1").Cells(b, 11))
    .TypeParagraph
    .TypeText Text:="test"
    .TypeParagraph
End With

'write table

Set objtable = objdoc.Tables.Add(objrange, cn, 2)
objtable.AutoFormat (16)

'populate table

For cpopulate = 0 To cn - 1
    With objtable
        .Cell(cpopulate + 1, 1).Range.Text = Cells(i + cpopulate, 1)
        .Cell(cpopulate + 1, 2).Range.Text = CStr(Cells(i + cpoppulate, 10))
    End With
Next cpopulate
```

Comment: This approach seem slightly simpler and straight forward rather than creating an empty table and then filling it with data: http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/5/22/copy-paste-an-excel-table-into-microsoft-word-with-vba

Comment: @Ralph the problem with that is it copies and entire range, theres more to the code ive developed which takes specific cells so i cant use that approach

Comment: @Ralph the program also collates a specific number of cells per table, based on a set of criteria, making the table length a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess my above comment was too short to really ensure that you catch my drift. What I am trying to say is that it is **much** easier (at least to me) to create a table in Excel then it is in Word.

This is especially the case when you have all the `Cells()` and `Range()` references (in VBA) at your disposal to quickly address each cell and fill it with the data you want. Afterwards, you might even want to consider listing it as a `ListObject` and applying a nice little preset on that table.

Once the table is finished and contains all the data that you want and is formatted as you wish you can easily copy the final table over with two simple lines of code:

```
ws.Range("A1:G20").Copy
objDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False
```

To make things even easier you can use a "temporary" sheet for that purpose which gets immediately deleted once you have copied over the table:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyTableToWord()

Dim ws As Worksheet

'Setup a temporary sheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

'here should be your above code to fill the table with all the data that you want / need
'afterwards you may even want to format that table

'... and then you can easily copy over the final table to Word
ws.Range("A1:G20").Copy     '... or whatever the resulting range will be
objDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False

'... remove the temporary sheet afterwards if you wish or keep it
'    so you don't have to recreate it each time
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ws.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```